# SQL Server Crashes

Tags: sql-server-2008

From yesterday SQL Server Service just randomly stops, I am not sure what is causing this to happen, but here is the Event Log on our server, we are using SQL Server 2008 R2

A fatal error occurred in the .NET Framework common language runtime. SQL Server is shutting down. If the error recurs after the server is restarted, contact Customer Support Services.

Comment: I would suggest rolling back whatever change you made to the application or database just before this started happening. Then you have time to fix it.

Comment: There was no database changes, however lqbal answered my question