# SQL Server 2016 - A fatal error occurred in the .net framework common language runtime. sql server is shutting down

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2016 version is crashing every time. I am getting the following error message:

[image]

I have tried to run the latest Cumulative Update for SQL 2016 but no luck.

Also, I have gone through online materials/potential fixes but didnt get a solution. Here are some of the links I have gone to:

[SQL Server Crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660115/sql-server-crashes)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981108/fix-error-message-when-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-or-the-sql-s

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b0e6154-89ae-406c-a786-28801bb52e21/need-help-quota-fatal-error-occurred-in-the-net-framework-common-language-runtime-sql-server-is?forum=sqlnetfx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981108/fix-error-message-when-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-or-the-sql-s

Can someone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall and re-install sql server